# Dual or multi boot to a pre-installed/existing windows 7 on another drive without fresh install

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, bootloader

I have a laptop that has working Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise edition on Drive0 which is an HDD. I have switched this HDD from Drive0 into Drive1 and plugged a new SSD into Drive0.

I then install a fresh window 10 to new SSD on Drive0.

Can I dual/multi boot to my previous pre-installed/existing windows 7 (without doing a new/fresh install) which is now on Drive1? If yes, how can I?

Or if I can achieve this by running repair of Windows 7 installation which can preserve my previous windows 7 installation.

Comment: Is there a reason for not leaving the HDD as drive 0, adding the SSD as drive 1, then installing Win 10 onto the drive 1 SSD, in which case it will create a multi-boot menu? Note - if Win 10 is default boot OS, a reboot partially boots into Win 10, if Win 7 is default boot OS, a reboot occurs much quicker, displaying a text menu to choose which OS to boot into.

Comment: @rcgldr . Initially I have done like you mentioned. i.e, drive0 was having Win7 and I tried installing fersh Win10 to new Drive1, but it was not giving me multi-boot menu for some reason. And now, as I have switched the drives(as mentioned in the post), I am trying to find a way to preserve both my installations and avoid any new install which override my previous installation.